# mb_detect_encoding $this context error in PHP 5.3

Tags: php

I recently run into a unusual problem in a 5.3 server (yeah it is outdated, but it's not up to me to update it).
The `$this->encodings` part in the `mb_detect_encoding` caused fatal error:

> "Using $this when not in object context"

It worked fine on 5.5 when i tried - for what reason would it fail in a older version of PHP? Would it be `array_map` callback that breaks it?

```
  public function getNextLine()
  {
    $csvRow = fgetcsv($this->fileHandler, 0, $this->separator, $this->enclosure); 
    if ($csvRow && is_array($csvRow))
    {
      array_map( function($str) {
        return iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str, $this->encodings, true), 'UTF-8', $str);
      }, $csvRow );
      return $csvRow;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in PHP manual:

```
Version Description
5.4.0   $this can be used in anonymous functions.
```

[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

> For PHP 5.3 $this support for Closures was removed because no consensus could be reached how to implement it in a sane fashion.

Possible workaround would be to re-assign this to another variable and pass it via `use`:

```
$_this = $this;
function() use($_this) { ... }
```

Comment: So starting from 5.4 it now works. Another one of the hidden  features easy to miss and  annoying to debug and find out. Never really having to deal with scope issues in PHP.

Comment: For PHP 5.3 $this support for Closures was removed because no consensus could be reached how to implement it in a sane fashion. Yes,  from 5.4 it now works.